# How do I store information collected from a for loop and assign it to a variable with the count iteration?

Tags: python

I am creating a program that will take input, and output opening and closing html tags around the input in a list. Obviously the code below will just print the last input that was entered on the last run `count` times. I would guess that a new variable must be created based on the `count` during each pass. How do I accomplish this?

```
runNum = int( input( "How many items are you entering? : "))
print ("Type 1 if you would like to use the li tag or type 2 for the th tag")
descVar = input("")
if descVar == "1":
    for count in range ( 1, runNum + 1):
        print ("Please enter item #", count, "")
        item = input()


    for count in range (1, runNum):
        print ( <li>, item, </li> )
```

Comment: @MorganThrapp Care to explain in more detail. I am new to cs/python.

Comment: Use the count as the key and the thing you want to associate with the count as a value. You might want to read the docs on dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just collect the input in a list:

```
items = []
for count in range ( 1, runNum + 1):
        print ("Please enter item #", count, "")
        item = input()
        items.append(item)

for item in items:
        print ("<li>",item,"</li>")
```

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thanks, that helped me see how it all comes together!